# Changing location of settings files in PyCharm Community 2016.3.2

Tags: pycharm

My PyCharm Community 2016.3.2 event log is being flooded with these types of errors:

> 9:02 AM   Load Settings
>
> Cannot load settings from file 'E:\foo\bar\pycharmcommunity\2016.3.2.PyCharmCE\config\options\packages.xml': E:\foo\bar\pycharmcommunity\2016.3.2.PyCharmCE\config\options\packages.xml
>
> File content will be recreated

I've tried:

- Invalidating the cache and restarting, but no luck
- Reinstalling the program, but in my case, no luck
- Navigating to the `E:\foo\bar\pycharmcommunity\2016.3.2.PyCharmCE\config\options` directory, deleting the `packages.xml___jb_old___` and `packages.xml___jb_tmp___` files that get created, but they just come back
- Creating `packages.xml` manually yields the error: `"The file or folder does not exist."`

Can I specify the location that these settings files are written to?

Comment: What does the PyCharm documentation have to say about changing the location of the PyCharm configuration files?

Comment: @Ramhound Nothing? The documentation and the IntelliJ support forum were the first places I looked.